# 2D animation, Line between meshes

Tags: animation, mesh, bezier-curves

I'm pretty new to blender so it might be a silly question to you. I try to create a 2D animated logo

I was able to animate two mesh objects, both move around. Now I want to connect both with a line. Each end of line should follow one object. As result, the line gets streched, compressed, rotates and so on.

I was able to do so with an additional pane mesh and manually set lots of keyframes (LocRotScale). This is a lot of work and I'm wondering if I could do it faster. Also by scaling the mesh with keyframes, it can become really thin so you can't see it anymore for a while.

I found out that it should be able by using either a curve mesh or a mesh containing just two points. I tried to create a curve, select one point and select the mesh I want to attach and press CTRL + H to hook this end of curve to the mesh. Now I did the same for the other end.

When running animation now, the curve stays unchanged while the meshes walk around. In outliner, I can see that the curve object has two hooks attached to the meshes, so the hooks seems to be ok.

It would be glad if someone could explain step-by-step what I have to do.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: I think this would benefit from some images of what you’ve already achieved to give more of an idea of your goal. Please edit your question to add useful images to illustrate. Also, this seems to be two questions (1 = a better way than using keyframes, 2 = hooked curve not working). This site wirks best with one issue per question. Please consider splitting into two seperate qyestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if i understood you correctly, but I try it anyways.
I used a Path with a Circle as a Bevel Object. Watch in the Path settings. The Bevel Circle is on Layer 2.

**The workflow for Hook 2 Objects:**

1. Select your Mesh
2. Shift+Select your Path
3. Press TAB to switch to Edit Mode
4. Select the Point of the Path you want to Hook to
5. Ctrl+H > Hook to selected Object
6. Done

[image]

Here is an example File. I hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was now able to hook the ends of curve to my objects.